# Testflight internal testing unable to add group

Tags: ios, build, app-store-connect, testflight

Normally when I create archive and click distribute from xCode. It automatically selects to test group and send each person to mail about update. But know when archived and send it to appstore connect now I am not able to add group and it is not seen in testflight. In Internal groups I cant even lick TESTER[image]

Comment: Same Issue here :(

Comment: Fixed problem via uploading .ipa file via transporter app now its working.

Comment: I also faced this issue twice. Issue resolved only after I uploaded build again with incrementing build no.

Answer (score 0):

Increment the build no and upload new build again. This is the solution I have for this issue.